# reading from a text file: strange "\x01\0\0\0" sequences

Tags: c, xcode, file, text, stream

I have been struggling with this issue for one week, and still far away from the solution.

I am reading a plain text from a file by strings. It reads everything successfully until a character with a certain large number.
This number is specific for each file, and is different for different files.

After reaching the character with this large number, it reads "\x01\0\0\0" sequences (consist of 4 chars) for one or more times instead of the original characters, and then reads everything correctly (until the next large number).

In a couple of words - instead of reading this:

```
... many characters ...
First read failure!
... many characters ...
Second read failure, second read failure!
... many characters ...
etc.
```

it reads this:

```
... many characters ...
First read f\x01\0\0\0re
... many characters ...
Second read failu\x01\0\0\0\x01\0\0\0\x01\0\0\0ead failure!
... many characters ...
etc.
```

Do you have any ideas about the cause of this problem?

Additional information:

```
 1) The "ferror" condition is not true.
 2) I am reading from file using streams (fopen, fread, fclose)
 3) Have tested different read methods: "fread cycle" and "fgets".
    The results are the same.
 4) The binary optimization is disabled in the compiler's settings.
    It seams that the problem is not connected with a compiler.
    Neither GCC, nor Apple LLVM gives me the desired result.
 5) Attempting to solve the issue, I converted the whole project from C++ to C,
    but the problem doesn't disappear.
```

Comment: This could be a hardware failure, or a bug in your program (some buffer overflow perhaps). Are you sure that the disk is in good condition? (Has the file system been checked recently thru `fsck`or similar?)  Did you check with an editor that your textual file has the content you believe it has? How was the textual file produced? Or perhaps the producer of that file is buggy. Or perhaps system misconfiguration issues (character encoding...). Did you run your program with `valgrind` ?

Comment: You really should show us the code if you want help here... Did you use your debugger ??

Comment: Are you sure that those characters are not in the file? They might not show up when looking at them as text, since they are non-printable.

Comment: I have tested my hard drive, it is 100% healthy.

Comment: @Thomas Padron-McCarthy Yes, the characters could be in file and not printable, but that doesn't explain where are my original characters gone. From the example above: "ailu" and "re, second r" are missing!

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I have used `fread(&c,1,1,in);` construction for reading and  `if (c=='\x01') {c='\x01';}` construction for debugging (it is placed just after fread, with a breakpoint turned on).

Comment: Did you check both the reader and the writer with `valgrind` for buffer overflows? But to get real help, you should show us real source code.

Comment: Have you checked with an hex editor if the text file is really how it should be ?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch OK, here is the reading function: `int readline(FILE *in, char * buf) {
    char c;
    buf[0]='\0';
    for (int i=0; i<BUFSIZ-1; i++) {
    fread(&c,1,1,in);
    if (ferror(in)) return 1;
    if (feof(in)) break;
    buf[i]=c;
    if (c=='\x01') {
    c='\x01'; // <------- breakpoint here
    }
    if (c=='\n') break;
    }
    if (buf[BUFSIZ-1]!='\0') return 1;
    return 0;
}`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch If I will replace the whole body of function with `fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, in);`, it will read it incorrectly too.

Comment: Put the code in the question. Why don't you use `getline` which is in POSIX 2008 standard? And you code smells like a buffer overflow... (We still have no idea how your function is called).

Comment: @Coren Have checked it with hex editor. The file is exactly how it should be: doesn't contain these \x01\0\0\0 characters, and contains the original characters in that place.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That is really strange, but `getline` solves the issue! It reads everything correctly - including those places where fgets and fread failed (they got '\x01\0\0\0' instead of real characters). Do you have any idea why getline works, while fread and fgets doesn't? (you would get "best answer" anyway)

Comment: `fread` and `fgets` do work as their specification says. But you used them incorrectly (buffer overflow, very probably, in your `readline` calls occurrence). And when using `getline` don't forget to later (once you close your file) free the `malloc`-ed buffer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Just add the answer below, and I will choose it as the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in comments:

- you should put your source code in the question (which you can always edit to improve it), not in comments
- you should use POSIX 2008 [getline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function on your `FILE*`.
- you should `free` the buffer implicitly `malloc`-ed by `getline` later, e.g. when `fclose`-ing your `FILE*` handle.
- you should learn to use a debugger like `gdb`
- you should learn to use a memory leakage detector like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) does not necessarily NUL terminate the input. You need to check the return value and terminate the string yourself if you want to treat the input as a string

```
chk = fread(input, <WHATEVER>);
if (chk > 0) {
    input[chk] = 0; /* terminate input */
    /* WHATEVER */
}
```

Comment: The fread cycle checks for NULL characters, as well as EOL and EOF.

Comment: How does the cycle test for stuff? I think you are using string functions with some non-string data.

Comment: Here is the code:
    
    `int readline(FILE *in, char * buf) { char c; buf[0]='\0'; for (int i=0; i<BUFSIZ-1; i++) { fread(&c,1,1,in); if (ferror(in)) return 1; if (feof(in)) break; buf[i]=c; if (c=='\x01') { c='\x01'; // <------- breakpoint here } if (c=='\n') break; } if (buf[BUFSIZ-1]!='\0') return 1; return 0; }`

Comment: The problem is that even if I replace the whole body of function with a simple fgets, it still reads incorrectly. Only getline c function reads correct.